# What do %lo and %hi in compiler-generated asm mean, and why doesn't it work on MARS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Can someone explain to me what this does

```
    %lo(foo)($1)
    %hi(foo)
```

specifically in this context:

```
    lui $1, %hi(foo)         
    sw $0, %lo(foo)($1)
```

What does the `($1)` do in `%lo(foo)($1)`?

Why does doing this not work on MARS?

Comment: Doesn't look like valid MIPS assembly to me unless they're some sort of compiler macro or function calls

Comment: You should be able to simply write `sw $0,foo` if you're using SPIM/MARS. Or you could write `la $1,foo` / `sw $0,($1)`

Answer (score 3):

That’s indirect addressing using the high and low 16 bits of foo as offsets in gas.  $0 and $1 are registers. See here: http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2004-08/msg00262.html